# Python on a chromebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, chromebook

I was wondering if there was any way to Run python 3.x on a chromebook as I am thinking of getting one but it would be no use if I couldn't program on it.

Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to install crouton:

http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/

Basically crouton installs a linux shell, from which you can download what you please.

To enter the shell after this, type the following into `crosh` (entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tt</kbd>)

```
$ shell
chronos@localhost-$ sudo enter-chroot
Entering usr/locals/precise...
user@localhost-$ echo This is the shell
This is the shell
```